# Correct way to check if value exists and is an array with items

Tags: php, arrays

So one way to do it would be..

```
if(isset($arrayVar)) {
    if(is_array($arrayVar)) {
        if(count($arrayVar) > 0) {
            // Success
            print_r($arrayVar);
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using [is_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-array.php) and [empty](http://php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php):

```
if (!empty($arrayVar) && is_array($arrayVar)) {
 // ...
}
```

`empty()` will check if isset and not empty at once.

Comment: Thank you! That's great info

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!empty($arrayVar) && is_array($arrayVar))
```

`!empty` covers both `isset` and empty arrays (all *falsey* values in fact), you then just need to confirm that it's also actually an array.

Answer (score -1):

You can check like this,

```
if(is_array($arrayVar) && sizeof($arrayVar) > 0)
{
   echo 'Array value exists';
}
else
{   
   echo 'array empty or it is not array';
}
```

Comment: Does not cover `isset`.